# How to insert data in mongodb using mongoose in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I had implemented a typescript code for a crud API but currently, I'm facing an issue while inserting data using API using the mongoose package. AS my database is MongoDB so I have used this package.

```
import Transaction from 'mongoose-transactions-typescript';
```

I am working on typescript project so that's why I have used this package

```
public async createAffiliateUser(res_data: any){
        console.log("Function");
```

> **const transaction = new Transaction();**

```
        console.log("Function123");
        const AffiliateUserModelName = 'affiliateusers'; // COLLECTION name
        console.log(res_data);
        await transaction.insert(AffiliateUserModelName, {
            name: res_data.name,
            userName: res_data.userName,
            groupId: res_data.groupId,
            commissionCount: res_data.commissionCount,
            commissionAmount: res_data.commissionAmount,
            is_active: res_data.is_active
        });
        
        return await transaction.run();
    }
```

In the above code highlighted line throwing an error like this

```
TypeError:mongoose_transactions_typescript_1.default is not a constructor
```

In the above function when I tried to use default create method of mongoose it inserting only single column data even though passing full data as below

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "userName":"test123",
    "groupId": "1",
    "commissionCount": 1,
    "commissionAmount": 2,
    "is_active": true
}
```

So if anyone knows how to insert data in MongoDB using typescript or a solution for the above problem then pls help me to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you use `import Transaction from 'mongoose-transactions';` instead?

Comment: @EzraChang that also throwing the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why are you using this code structure in order to use mongoose.

The steps that I follow in order to use correctly mongodb documents with mongoose are these:

1. create a mongoose model schema like this:

```js
// I usually like create this file in a database folder
import mongoose, { Document, Model } from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// creating the actual mongoose schema

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
    },
    lang: {
      type: String,
      default: "it",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// exporting the type in order to have all the correct linting

export interface IUser extends Document {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName?: string;
  username?: string;
  createdAt: Date | number;
  updatedAt: Date | number;
}

// registering in mongoose models the schema with the relative interface

const User =
  (mongoose.models.User as Model<IUser>) ||
  mongoose.model<IUser>("User", UserSchema);
export default User;
```

at this point let's suppose that you have a tree similar to this:

```
root_folder
          |-- database
          |        |-- User.ts
          |
          |-- controllers
                      |-- addUser.ts
```

2. creating the document in the collection:

```js
import { User } from "../../database/User.ts"

async function addUser(){
  const newUser = await new User({firstName: "foo", lastName: "bar", username:"testUser"}).save()
}
```

and now you should have your fresh document in the users collection